# Apache htacces RewriteRule to file with path equal to uri

Tags: .htaccess, file, dictionary, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all requests given to my server that contains the string 'track/' to a pdf file ubicated in the same path as the requested uri.

URL: http://www.whatever.com/track/Adelanto

```
 RewriteRule ^/?track/(.*)$ track/Adelanto/file.pdf
```

This is hardcoded for this example. I would like to have this dynamic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write this rule in your `htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/track/)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.pdf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/file.pdf [L,QSA,R]
```

You can see the htaccess file I have created for you here (https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=9ae812dd-54f6-596a-8b43-2ce1e8042e05)

Cheers

Comment: It's an infinite bucle.

Comment: Right. I have updated my answer. I have added a check whether `.pdf` is already there in url or not. Let me know how it works.